# Send multiple API requests simultaneously with different authorization header for each API Call request using Java

Tags: java, multithreading, api

I am struggling in sending multiple API requests simultaneously, below are the steps of which I am doing in order to send multiple API calls simultaneously:

1. Creating hashmap with 40 authorization values.
2. iterating over the hashmap in order to retrieve different authorization value for each call.

I know how to make it sequentially, I want to be able to do it with threads.

This is my code:

```
private void createUsers() throws ApiException {
    AuthAPI authAPI = new AuthAPI(HOST);
    usersMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 40 - 1; i++) {
        String USER_NAME = "Introductory Content User " + StringUtils.getRandomString(5, true, false);
        usersAPIUnitTest.createUser(USER_NAME, UserRole.ADMIN, "", "", "");
        String email = UsersAPIUnitTest.getEmail();
        System.out.println(email);
        String userToken = authAPI.generateToken(email);
        usersMap.put(USER_NAME, userToken);
    }
}
```

Then I use this method to send the api calls:

```
public void sendMultipleAPIRequests() throws IOException {
        for(Map.Entry mapElement : usersMap.entrySet()){
            LabAPIChecker labAPIChecker = new LabAPIChecker(HOST, mapElement.getValue());
            JsonObject jsonObject = labAPIChecker.launchLabGetRequest();//this line perform simple 'get' request
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this with standard java tools. You will need to use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) or possibly just an `ExecutorService` To get an istance of one use [Executors] class[2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). You will need to create (or modify) your own class to implement `Runnable` interface where method `run()` would be responsible for sending a single request. Than you will need to submit all your Runnables to your ScheduledExecutorService to run at the same time. Set the number of threads equal to the number of your runnables and they will run concurrently

Answer (score 1):

The resulting code following @michael-gantman suggestion:

```
public void sendMultipleAPIRequests() throws IOException 
{
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // max 10 concurrent threads
    for (Map.Entry mapElement : usersMap.entrySet()) {
        Runnable thread = () -> {
          LabAPIChecker labAPIChecker = new LabAPIChecker(HOST, mapElement.getValue());
          JsonObject jsonObject = labAPIChecker.launchLabGetRequest();
        };
        executorService.execute(thread);
     }
     executorService.shutdown(); 
 }
```

All credit goes to @michael-gantman

Comment: In the thread pool you set the number of threads which indicate the number of threads that will send the request simultaneously?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco - nice implementation, and thanks for the credit

Comment: @tupacshakur yes, number of threads is the number of threads in that thread pool, which means that at any moment it can run up to 10 tasks simultaneously. To truly achieve concurrency you may want to use ScheduledExecutorService and schedule your tasks to start at the same time and set the number of threads to the number of your tasks. But that might be an overkill

Comment: and another question if I can ask, after I got the JsonObject as a response from the API request call, I check that in a field called "status" if the value is "ready" in 90 seconds (it can be in any other status:[Error, pending]) I want to perform the API request again till the 90 seconds will be over and it will notify by printing it in the console.